# Clear Billing Address when change Billing State Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, checkout

When i change "Billing State", the "Billing City" field it resets (thats ok)
But the "Billing Address 1" keeps the same information.

For Example i select **(State='Lima', City='Miraflores', Address 1='Av. Jose Larco293')** 
When i change Lima to other State it shows like **('Arequipa', ' - ', 'Av. Jose Larco293')**

I would also like the "Billing Address 1" to be clear emptied when change state, thanks.

Comment: you can clear the billing address with jquery (on the onchange event of the state input). are you familiar with jquery?

Comment: btw: it would help if you added the HTML code of those 3 form fields.

Comment: @jasie I know how to add jquery codes but not the code itself, State id="billing_state_field", City id="billing_city_field", Address 1 id="billing_address_1_field", my website is https://chillandstick.com/  Sorry is in spanish.

Comment: Its work! with on Change event! thank you

Comment: glad I could help. use the opportunity and answer your own question. paste your code and explain it :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the code i make to solution this! just post on Functions.php and work for others options just change. (is_page '61' = Checkout Page for me)

Thanks

```
function wpb_hook_javascript() {
  if (is_page ('61')) { 
    ?>
       
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
             $("#billing_state_field").change(function() {
            $("#billing_address_1").val("");
        })
    })
           ;
        </script>
     <?php
  }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'wpb_hook_javascript');
```